# What is the most useful type of java.awt.image.BufferedImage for off-screen rendering?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, awt

I am creating a buffered image that is going to be a snapshot of a JComponent (via paint()) and rendered inside an [ImageIcon](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html).  There are a large amount of types in the [`BufferedImage(int width, int height, int imageType)`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#BufferedImage(int,%20int,%20int)) constructor, but which one should I use?

I am sure that any of them would work, but which ones are better than the others?  How should I pick one? And Why?

Comment: I think the question as it stands now is perfectly constructive. Heck the answer answered the question I came here with!

Comment: I reworked it to better fit the best answer, which points to an API that you should use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [GraphicsConfiguration.createCompatibleImage(int, int)](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsConfiguration.html#createCompatibleImage(int,%20int)) for a helper to create a BufferedImage of a "good" type among the many available types.

How to get your hands on a GraphicsConfiguration instance to make this call?  It depends on where your code is executing.  See the [many methods](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/class-use/GraphicsConfiguration.html) for getting your hands on a GraphicsConfiguration via methods like getGraphicsConfiguration() or getDeviceConfiguration().

Comment: If you only had a code snippet instead of a javadoc link you would so get the answer.

Comment: be careful iterating over graphics configurations.  depending on your hardware, some of those methods take several seconds the first time.

Comment: yes, what is X?  No check mark with such unsure code snippets.

Comment: I will have to live forever without the sweet, sweet feeling of this particular check mark.  Oh, what might have been...

Comment: and don't forget to fromat it properly by putting in four spaces in the front.

Comment: This is the easiest way `GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().getDefaultConfiguration().createCompatibleImage(width, height);`